# Problem with internet speed checking with speedtest --simple

Tags: command-line, networking, download-speed

Long story short. I had Ubuntu 18 on my system. I installed

```
sudo apt install speedtest-cli
```

to track internet speeds. I have a log copied from the terminal of the output on various days.

- Download: 8.86 Mbit/s
- Upload: 2.24 Mbit/s (typical)
- Download: 11.67 Mbit/s
- Upload: 2.22 Mbit/s

Then I had to reinstall the OS. (long story) Then I re-installed `speedtest`. It constantly times out. I ran the command

```
speedtest-cli --timeout 60
```

and the best result I could get is:

- Download: 1.17 Mbit/s
- Upload: 1.01 Mbit/s

AS YOU CAN SEE (A SIGNIFICANT DROP IN SPEED) Everything else, equipment, service etc. is the same.

How do I fix this problem without re-installing the OS?

Comment: What is the speed of your Internet service? Do you have QoS enabled in your router?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you're using the same driver for your network card? Are we talking about wifi or ethernet connection? Please post the results of the following command run in a terminal:  `inxi -Fxzd`